# Scala generic function for dividing a collection by modulo

Tags: scala

I want to evenly divide a collection into several groups and here is my code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object MyCollection {

  def divideByModulo[A](items: Array[A], div: Int): Array[Array[A]] = {
    require(items.size >= div)
    val itemSets = (0 until div) map { i => ArrayBuffer(items(i)) }

    for (i <- div until items.size)
      itemSets(i % div) += items(i)

    itemSets.toArray map { _.toArray }
  }
}
```

However, when compiling the above code, errors appear as follows:

```
[error] MyCollection.scala:13: No ClassTag available for A
[error]     itemSets.toArray map { s: ArrayBuffer[A] => s.toArray }
[error]                                                   ^
[error] MyCollection.scala:13: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[Nothing]
[error]  required: Array[Array[A]]
[error] Note: Nothing <: Array[A], but class Array is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Array[A]`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]     itemSets.toArray map { _.toArray }
[error]                      ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I cannot figure out what is the problem. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `ArrayBuffer.toArray`, the code must instantiate a new `Array[A]`, but the Java language implements generics by erasure, and the exact type of A is not available at runtime unless you do something special. The special thing that you do is provide a 'hint' which boils down to adding `ClassTag` as a context bound to `divideByModulo` in this way:

```
divideByModulo[A : ClassTag]: Array[Array[A]] = {...}
```

`Array`s and why this is necessary is discussed in more detail [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_38.html).

Although the error you're seeing seems inscrutable, you can recreate the underlying problem, by writing this simpler function:

```
def mkArray[T](elems: T*) = Array[T](elems: _*)
```

which results in the error `No ClassTag available for T`.

Also, you may want to consider using other collection types rather than `Array`s due to the fact that they where really designed to be used when interoperating with Java libraries rather than as general purpose collections. Additionally, `Array`s are mutable and immutability is preferred in the Scala language by convention and encouraged by the libraries. For instance, you can also solve your compilation error by changing the return type to `Seq[Seq[A]]` and converting your `ArrayBuffer`s to `Seq`s:

```
itemSets.toSeq map { _.toSeq }
```

And now, in addition to solving the compilation error, you get the added advantage that collections are immutable -- at least with respect to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, **`grouped`** is what you want to split the Array into several groups.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
object MyCollection extends  App {
    /*
       As toArray uses context bound, so you have to claim here;
       that is the reason compiler complains "No ClassTag available for A" in your case
       def toArray[B >: A : ClassTag]: Array[B] = {
    */
    def divideByModulo[A: ClassTag](items: Array[A], div: Int): Array[Array[A]] = {
        require(items.size >= div)
        items.grouped(div).toArray
    }

    /*
        converting to list is just for displaying result
        List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))
    */
   println(divideByModulo(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6),3).toList.map(_.toList))
}
```

Comment: The parameter to **grouped** specifies the number of items per group, rather than the number of total groups.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your method signature to:

```
def divideByModulo[A:ClassTag](items: Array[A], div: Int): Array[Array[A]]
```

I would implement this method more functional-style:

```
def divideByModulo[A:ClassTag](items: Array[A], div: Int):Array[Array[A]] = {
  require(items.size >= div)
  require(div!=0)
  items.zipWithIndex.groupBy(_._2 % div).values.map(_.map (_._1)).toArray
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your implementation is graceful.